# Ruby Containers and Complexities

Tags: ruby, hash, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of accessing something like `hash[:value1][:value2]`?

If I had a method where this appeared multiple times, would it be better to assign this to a variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby Language Specification does not actually formally guarantee any particular performance characteristics, however, all Ruby implementations implement Ruby `Hash`es using the typical performance characteristics for a dynamic dictionary: O(n) worst-case time complexity and O(1) amortized worst-case time complexity for insertion, deletion and random access. And even though those are not guaranteed by the Specification, those are what the community expects, and any implementation that doesn't meet those will probably not be accepted by the community.

Rubinius has an alternative implementation of `Hash` based on a Hash Array Mapped Trie, which can be optionally activated with a command line switch, which will presumably have O(log n) (but with a high branching factor) for all of those, I think. (I haven't checked.)